# Disable drag to dismiss in SwiftUI Modal

Tags: swiftui

I've presented a modal view but I would like the user to go through some steps before it can be dismissed.
Currently the view can be dragged to dismiss.

Is there a way to stop this from being possible?

I've watched the WWDC Session videos and they mention it but I can't seem to put my finger on the exact code I'd need.

```swift
struct OnboardingView2 : View {

    @Binding
    var dismissFlag: Bool

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("Onboarding here! ")
            Button(action: {
                self.dismissFlag.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Dismiss")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I currently have some text and a button I'm going to use at a later date to dismiss the view.

Comment: Rob, Could you please post the link of the mentioned WWDC video?

Comment: @Prcela it doesn't sounds like it - he's asking how to disable the gesture recognizer

Comment: @Prcela different question I'd say :)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @konrad.bajtyngier If you are still looking I posted a way that does not use an overlay (ZStack) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60939207/6433690

Answer (score 29):

### iOS 15+

Starting from iOS 15 we can use `interactiveDismissDisabled`:

```
func interactiveDismissDisabled(_ isDisabled: Bool = true) -> some View
```

We just need to attach it to the sheet. Here is an example from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/interactivedismissdisabled(_:)):

```
struct PresentingView: View {
    @Binding var showTerms: Bool

    var body: some View {
        AppContents()
            .sheet(isPresented: $showTerms) {
                Sheet()
            }
    }
}

struct Sheet: View {
    @State private var acceptedTerms = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Button("Accept Terms") {
                acceptedTerms = true
            }
        }
        .interactiveDismissDisabled(!acceptedTerms)
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked beautifully
Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It is easy if you use the 3rd party lib [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect), which is very useful as it access the corresponding UIKit component easily. In this case, the property in `UIViewController`:

```
VStack { ... }
.introspectViewController {
    $0.isModalInPresentation = true
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, took me seconds through swift package manager and seconds to add it..

Comment: This worked for me, but only if I applied the modifier to the root view in the `.sheet` modifier. If I applied it to subviews, it had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this helps or even the method to show the modal you are using but when you present a SwiftUI view from a `UIViewController` using `UIHostingController`

```
let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: <#your swiftUI view#>(<#your parameters #>))
```

you can set a `modalPresentationStyle`. You may have to decide which of the styles suits your needs but `.currentContext` prevents the dragging to dismiss.

Side note:I don't know how to dismiss a view presented from a `UIHostingController` though which is why I've asked a Q myself on here to find out

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56529505/present-a-view-non-modally)

```
struct Start : View {
let destinationView = SetUp()
    .navigationBarItem(title: Text("Set Up View"), titleDisplayMode: .automatic, hidesBackButton: true)

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationButton(destination: destinationView) {
            Text("Set Up")

        }
    }
}
}
```

The main thing here is that it is hiding the back button. This turns off the back button and makes it so the user can't swipe back ether.

For the setup portion of your app you could create a new SwiftUI file and add a similar thing to get home, while also incorporating your own setup code.

```
struct SetUp : View {

    let destinationView = Text("Your App Here")
        .navigationBarItem(title: Text("Your all set up!"), titleDisplayMode: .automatic, hidesBackButton: true)

 var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationButton(destination: destinationView) {
            Text("Done")

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS13+ solution:

This is actually very easy to do using only standard API. Wrap the contents of your sheet into NavigationView and add DragGesture on navigation view using .gesture or .simultaneousGesture. This will cancel-out internal sheet drag gesture. This method is tested and works on all iOS versions iOS13+.

iOS 13+ example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show") {
            isPresented = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Text("Test View")
                }
                .navigationBarItems(
                    trailing:
                        Button {
                            isPresented = false
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                                .renderingMode(.template)
                                .foregroundColor(.primary.opacity(0.5))
                        }
                )
            }
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 1, coordinateSpace: .local)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Modifier to disable interactive dismiss on older systems:

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func interactiveDismissDisabledLegacy(_ isDisabled: Bool = true) -> some View {
        if isDisabled {
            NavigationView {
                self
            }
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 1, coordinateSpace: .local)
            )
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

iOS15+ provides new modifier .interactiveDismissDisabled(true), which provides the same functionality. iOS 15+ example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show") {
            isPresented = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            VStack {
                Text("Test View")
            }
            .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is an extension to make controlling the modal dismission effortless, at https://gist.github.com/mobilinked/9b6086b3760bcf1e5432932dad0813c0

A temporary solution before the official solution released by Apple.

```
/// Example:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var presenting = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                presenting = true
            } label: {
                Text("Present")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $presenting) {
            ModalContent()
                .allowAutoDismiss { false }
                // or
                // .allowAutoDismiss(false)
        }
    }
}
```