# Is it possible to make a modal non-dismissible in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am creating an App where the login / register part is inside a modal, which is shown if the user is not logged in.

The problem is, that the user can dismiss the modal by swiping it down...

Is it possible to prevent this?

```
var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection) {
        App()
    }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) { // This needs to be non-dismissible
        LoginRegister()
    }
}
```

Second example:

I am using a modal to ask for information. The user should not be able to quit this process except by dismissing the modal with save button. The user has to input information before the button works. Unfortunately the modal can be dismissed by swiping it down.

Is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: Modals typically (as in most always) are made to be dismissed. Why not change your app design? Make your login be a complete `View`? Put it in a `ZStack` on top of whatever view you wish. Now you have 100% control (which you don't have with a modal) and can (a) animate presenting it, (b) keep it visible until your code says to dismiss it, and (c) animate dismissing it.

Comment: Starting from iOS 15 you can use `interactiveDismissDisabled` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68009509/8697793).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**iOS 15 and later:**

Use  `.interactiveDismissDisabled(true)` on the sheet, that's all.

**Prev iOS 15:**

You can try to do this by using a `highPriorityGesture`. Of course the blue Rectangle is only for demonstration but you would have to use a view which is covering the whole screen.

```
struct ModalViewNoClose : View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    let gesture = DragGesture()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 600)
            .highPriorityGesture(gesture)
            
            .overlay(
                VStack{
                    Button("Close") {
                        self.presentationMode.value.dismiss()
                    }.accentColor(.white)
                    Text("Modal")
                        .highPriorityGesture(gesture)
                    TextField("as", text: .constant("sdf"))
                        .highPriorityGesture(gesture)
                } .highPriorityGesture(gesture)
        )
            .border(Color.green)
    }
}
```

Comment: I will mark this as answer because it comes closest to what I asked for. Thanks it works great!

Comment: Unfortunately you can still use two or more fingers at once to dismiss the modal.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @user1302387 Did you solve it or perhaps try my method at at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60939207/6433690?

Answer (score 4):

This is a common problem and a "code smell"... well not really code but a "design pattern smell" anyway.

The problem is that you are making your login process part of the rest of the app.

Instead of presenting the `LoginRegister` over the `App` you should really be showing either `App` or `LoginRegister`.

i.e. you should have some state object like `userLoggedIn: Bool` or something and depending on that value you should show either `App` or `LoginRegister`.

Just don't have both in the view hierarchy at the same time. That way your user won't be able to dismiss the view.

Comment: Ok sorry I am in a bad mood! I know that I asked for an XY Problem, but I couldn't find anything on google and I thought maybe someone already tried that. I am merely experimenting, trying to figure out what's new. As I said this is an example use case... And you are right ... I don't know what I am doing...

Comment: @krjw no worries  it’s all good. It can be frustrating when you feel like you’ve tried everything and aren’t getting anywhere. Hope you can solve your problem.

Comment: I'd argue it isn't a bad idea to do something like this if you're "timing out" a user in a sensitive app (eg., banking/medical) - if a user doesn't use it for 5 minutes, show the auth screen modally, upon successful login dismiss. 

This allows the user to not lose their place in the app.

Answer (score 4):

If you dont mind using [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect):

```swift
import Introspect

@available(iOS 13, *)
extension View {
    /// A Boolean value indicating whether the view controller enforces a modal behavior.
    ///
    /// The default value of this property is `false`. When you set it to `true`, UIKit ignores events
    /// outside the view controller's bounds and prevents the interactive dismissal of the
    /// view controller while it is onscreen.
    public func isModalInPresentation(_ value: Bool) -> some View {
        introspectViewController {
            $0.isModalInPresentation = value
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
.sheet {
    VStack {
        ...
    }.isModalInPresentation(true)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### iOS 15+

Starting from iOS 15 you can use [`interactiveDismissDisabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/texteditor/interactivedismissdisabled(_:)).

You just need to attach it to the sheet:

```
var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection) {
        App()
    }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) {
        LoginRegister()
            .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
    }
}
```

Regarding your second example, you can pass a variable to control when the sheet is disabled:

```
.interactiveDismissDisabled(!isAllInformationProvided)
```

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/texteditor/interactivedismissdisabled(_:)).

Comment: Underrated answer

Answer (score 0):

theoretically this may help you (I didn't tryed it)

```
private var isDisplayedBind: Binding<Bool>{ Binding(get: { true }, set: { _ = $0 }) }
```

and usage:

```
content
    .sheet(isPresented: isDisplayedBind) { some sheet }
```