# Disable modal sheet drag gesture in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, gesture

I created a simple sheet that presents a basic few. The problem is, that this view contains a list that is also draggable. And so when I drag the list, my sheet gets dismissed too. Does anyone know how to disable the drag gesture on the sheet in SwiftUI or has a better idea?

Comment: Can you share a code example please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make a modal non-dismissible in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398353/is-it-possible-to-make-a-modal-non-dismissible-in-swiftui/57399626#57399626)