# Is there a way to put a condition on sheet dismissal in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to check for user active session on first view appearance in swiftUI and if theres no active session ,a sheet will be presented to ask for user credentials .

The problem I'm facing is the user can easily dismiss the sheet using swipe gesture or done button in navigation view , I want to disable the dismissal through these ways and only enable it programmatically, Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57399626/12647189

Comment: hope it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615408/prevent-dismissal-of-modal-view-controller-in-swiftui/61239704#61239704