# SwiftUI Modal View dismiss only with Button

Tags: swiftui

It's possible to dismiss a Modal View only with a Button? I don't want that the user can swipe down to dismiss the Modal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615408/prevent-dismissal-of-modal-view-controller-in-swiftui/58393024#58393024

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent dismissal of modal view controller in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615408/prevent-dismissal-of-modal-view-controller-in-swiftui)