# How to prevent sheet from dismissed with a confirmation dialog

Tags: swiftui

I use a sheet to display a form for user inputs. I hope to control the dismissing behavior based on whether there're (unsaved) inputs in the form. It's easy to do it for the "Cancel" button in toolbar, but how to enable that dialog for "swipe down to dismiss"?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false
    @State var showConfirmation = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Button("Show Sheet") {
                showSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            NavigationStack {
                Form {
                    TextField("Name", text: .constant("Hello, World."))
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                        Button("Cancel") {
                            showConfirmation = true
                        }
                    }
                }
                .confirmationDialog("", isPresented: $showConfirmation) {
                    Button("Discard Changes?", role: .destructive) {
                        showSheet = false
                    }
                }
                .interactiveDismissDisabled() // <-- How to enable the confirmation dialog for "swiping to dismiss" instead of simply preventing it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `onDismiss` handler to `.toggle()` your `.confirmationDialog` so now it will be shown every-time the `.sheet` is dismissed regardless of wether user dismisses it by clicking cancel or by swiping down.

Edit: I've updated this answer to now use a `gesture` which shows the confirmation dialog whenever user tries to swipe down to dismiss.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showSheet = false
    @State var showConfirmation = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Button("Show Sheet") {
                showSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            NavigationStack {
                Form {
                    TextField("Name", text: .constant("Hello, World."))
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                        Button("Cancel") {
                            showSheet = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .interactiveDismissDisabled()
            .confirmationDialog("", isPresented: $showConfirmation) {
                Button("Discard Changes?", role: .destructive) {
                    
                }
            }
            .gesture(
                DragGesture().onEnded({ value in
                if value.translation.height >= 10 {
                    showConfirmation.toggle()
                }
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how do you do this when dismissing is disabled with `.interactiveDismissDisabled()`? Add `.interactiveDismissDisabled()` to your sheet. The idea is that when a user attempts to dismiss, they are met with a confirmation dialog. In my use-case, if any of the fields have been edited, `interactiveDismissDisabled` is `true`, but if the form is untouched then `interactiveDismissDisabled` is `false` such that users may dismiss the sheet only if the form is untouched. If there are edits, they are instead met with a confirmation dialog.

Comment: You can't while you're using ```.interactiveDismissDisabled()```, instead I would suggest adding a ```dragGesture``` on top to detect if a user is trying to dismiss the sheet and then use that to show the confirmationDialog.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for `DragGesture`. It looks like a great solution! If you update your answer to explain the `DragGesture` workaround, I will give you the bounty.

Comment: @tedtanner updated answer with ```DragGesture```.

Comment: To be completely honest, this doesn't work very well. It seems that if I swipe anywhere inside the form, it doesn't catch the gesture

Comment: I found what I needed mixing UIKit and SwiftUI here, however: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61239704/8297052

Comment: ahh you had to resort to using UIKit, well that's unfortunate but why though I thought the dismiss modifier was working fine for you?

Comment: It was a great idea and it worked find when I had an empty view. But it is inconsistent when the sheet has subviews. Also, it overrides the sheet's own DragGesture

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, you need to use UIKit to get this behavior.

You'll need to create this UIKit `UIViewControllerRepresentable` that can be used from SwiftUI. The `presentationControllerDidAttemptToDismiss()` function is what allows us to capture attempted dismissals:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct MySheet<T: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let hostingController: UIHostingController<T>

    var onDismissAttempt: (() -> Void)?
    var allowDismissal: Bool // Don't use @Binding here. Only the initial value would be used.
                             // The update will be handled in updateUIViewController().

    init(allowDismissal: Bool, onDismissAttempt: (() -> Void)? = nil, _ content: () -> T) {
        self.onDismissAttempt = onDismissAttempt
        self.hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: content())
        self.allowDismissal = allowDismissal
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIHostingController<AnyView> {
        return self.hostingController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIHostingController<AnyView>, context: Context) {
        // These two lines are necessary to update allowDimsissal.
        context.coordinator.sheet = self
        uiViewController.rootView = self.hostingController.rootView

        uiViewController.parent?.presentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {
        var sheet: MySheet

        init(_ sheet: MySheet) {
            self.sheet = sheet
        }

        func presentationControllerShouldDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) -> Bool {
            self.sheet.allowDismissal
        }

        func presentationControllerDidAttemptToDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
            self.sheet.onDismissAttempt?()
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this in your SwiftUI like so. Anything in the `onDismissAttempt` closure will be run when a user attempts to dismiss the sheet when the sheet is not dismissable:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    @State var showingSheet = false // Controls whether the sheet is presented
    @State var showingSheetCloseConfirmation = false // Controls whether the confirmation modal is shown
    @State var canDismissSheet = true // Controls whether the sheet can be dismissed

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Content
        }
       .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingSheet) {
            // Your `MySheet` can be used like a normal SwiftUI view
            MySheet(allowDismissal: self.canDismissSheet, onDismissAttempt: {
               self.showingSheetCloseConfirmation = true
            }) {
                // Sheet content
                VStack {

                }
            }
        }
        .alert("Discard your changes?", isPresented: self.$showingSheetCloseConfirmation) {
            Button("Yes", role: .destructive) {
                self.showingSheetCloseConfirmation = false
                self.showingSheet = false
                self.canDismissSheet = true
            }
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
                self.showingSheetCloseConfirmation = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to figure this out thanks to this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61239704/8297052. If my answer was helpful, go and upvote that answer as well.